# Why submitted property of ngForm stay false after submit event?

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to trigger submit outside the form, and I use `submitted` property of `ngForm` for my app logic.

But when I submit the form, it trigger `onSubmit` function, but `submitted` stay `false`.

Why? and how make it work?

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-nv8lvy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

```
import { Component, VERSION, ViewChild } from "@angular/core";
import { FormControl, FormGroup, NgForm } from "@angular/forms";

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  @ViewChild("ngForm") form: NgForm;

  profileForm = new FormGroup({
    firstName: new FormControl(""),
    lastName: new FormControl("")
  });

  name = "Angular " + VERSION.major;

  submitForm() {
    this.form.ngSubmit.emit();
  }

  onSubmit() {
    console.log("submittedd!!!");
  }
}
```

Html:

```
<hello name="{{ name }}"></hello>
<p>
    Start editing to see some magic happen :)
</p>

{{ngForm.submitted | json }}

<form #ngForm="ngForm" [formGroup]="profileForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">

    <label>
    First Name:
    <input type="text" formControlName="firstName">
  </label>

    <label>
    Last Name:
    <input type="text" formControlName="lastName">
  </label>

</form>

<button type="button" (click)="submitForm()">trigger submit outside</button>
```

Comment: Emitting on the ngSubmit doesn't actually submit the form as far as I know.  I suggest moving the button inside the form, removing the click event binding and change the type to submit.  You won't need the submitForm function then.

Comment: @testpossessed This is also true.

Answer (score 0):

You're not that far away. A few changes would be needed:

Add `id="ngForm"` for form tag:

```
<form id="ngForm" #ngForm="ngForm" [formGroup]="profileForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
```

Replace button's type to `submit` and add additional attribute `form` with a value which was given to a form's id. In this case, it would be `ngForm`:

```
<button type="submit" form="ngForm">trigger submit outside</button>
```

Additionally, you don't need `submitForm` method anymore.

Now it will set the form as submitted.